# Random zip method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, random, rspec

Is there a way to use the [`zip` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) in a random way?
If this is my code

```
['top', 'left', 'z-index'].zip(['5px', '35px', '10']).each do |attribute, value|
  #not the actual code, just an example
  puts "#{attribute} is #{value}"
end
```

It will print always in the same order:

> top is 5px
>   left is 35px
>   z-index is 10

If I [`shuffle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) the arrays, then the elements will not match, so maybe it will print

> left is 5px

and so on...

**What I'd like to achieve is this, as I am using it in my `RSpec` tests:**

**FIRST RUN**

> top is 5px
>   left is 35px
>   z-index is 10

**SECOND RUN**

> left is 35px
>   top is 5px
>   z-index is 10

etc.

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) alert! Why should you necessarily use [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you apply `shuffle` after `zip`?

```
['top', 'left', 'z-index'].zip(['5px', '35px', '10']).shuffle.each do |attribute, value|
  #not the actual code, just an example
  puts "#{attribute} is #{value}"
end
```

Every time you run this you'll get a different output. Sometimes this:

```
z-index is 10
left is 35px
top is 5px
```

And sometimes this:

```
left is 35px
z-index is 10
top is 5px
```

And sometimes other permutations of those same 3 lines

Comment: that's it! easy and simple!

Answer (score 2):

Whether you need just a random shuffle, please refer to the answer provided by @user12341234

Whether you want to test *all* permutations, use this:

```
['top', 'left', 'z-index'].zip(['5px', '35px', '10'])
                          .permutation(3)
                          .each do |properties|
  properties.each do |attribute, value|
    #not the actual code, just an example
    puts "#{attribute} is #{value}"
  end
end
```

More info on [`Array#permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-permutation).

Comment: nice! but in this case I needed the answer from @user12341234. I'm sure your answer will be useful on other occasions!

Answer (score 1):

Why use [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) to create an intermediate array? If

```
a = ['top', 'left', 'z-index']
b = ['5px', '35px', '10']
```

it is simpler and more efficient to write:

```
a.each_index.to_a.shuffle.each { |idx| puts "%s is %s" % [a[idx], b[idx]] }
```

prints

```
z-index is 10
left is 35px 
top is 5px
```

Run it again and it may print

```
top is 5px
z-index is 10
left is 35px
```

Comment: this should be repeated three times right (as I want the three lines to be printed). but idx could be three times "2", so `z-index: 10` will be printed 3 times. or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right and thank you for pointing it out. I understood the question, but by the time I wrote my answer my little grey cells had tricked me into thinking it was a different question. I've fixed my answer, retaining the essence of my original answer.